# Exploring the internal features of Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, rss

In Firefox, RSS feeds are rendered using an in-built style and parser.
Therefore, I want to use Mozilla's RSS parsing code in my own website.

Where exactly is the RSS parser located in the browser source code?
If so, more specifically, does firefox use javascript to render the RSS feed to HTML?

Comment: does this question need to be improved?